# How pass ratelimit in app proxed by traefik by docker run command (passing labels)?

Tags: traefik

I launch a web app using a command similar to this:

```
docker run     --name whoami1  --network proxy    --label traefik.port=80  --label  traefik.basic.frontend.rule=Host:test.example.com       emilevauge/whoami
```

How pass the ratelimit using --label ?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably more practical for you to define a TOML file with your configuration to avoid passing a huge amount of labels:

As you can see [here](https://docs.traefik.io/configuration/commons/), in "Rate Limit" section:

```
[frontends]
    [frontends.frontend1]
      # ...
      [frontends.frontend1.ratelimit]
        extractorfunc = "client.ip"
          [frontends.frontend1.ratelimit.rateset.rateset1]
            period = "10s"
            average = 100
            burst = 200
          [frontends.frontend1.ratelimit.rateset.rateset2]
            period = "3s"
            average = 5
            burst = 10
```

you have to define 3 params per frontend.
A toml file would be clearer, imho.

Comment: it is not modularizable this method ... if i had a additional webapp .. i have to modify the file in a server already working. In addition if i introduce a error in that file what is th behaviour for the server with already N webapps working in production?